# PySpark - Concat columns into one column containing a list

Tags: pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe with 3 columns.

How do I "concat" columns 2 and 3 into a single column containing a list using PySpark?

If if helps, column 1 is a unique key, no duplicates.

Initial dataframe:

```
| Col1 | Col2   | Col3 |
------------------------
| 11   | 'a'    | 13   |
| 21   | 'b'    | 23   |
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
| Col1 | NewCol2   |
--------------------
| 11   | ['a', 13] |
| 21   | ['b', 23] |
```

I have considered lambda functions but did not find a way to apply them to multiple columns.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `.array()` , detail: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html

Comment: Does this work ? 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.select(F.array('Col2', 'Col3').alias('NewCol2'))
df.show()

Comment: you can use `array()`, but it'd require you to have all columns in the same data type. if you intend to retain the data types as well, you can create structs using [`struct()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html#pyspark-sql-functions-struct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column containing either an array or a struct. With pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

example_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (11, "a", 13),
        (21, "b", 23),
    ],
    ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"],
)
result_df_array = example_df.select(
    "Col1", F.array(F.col("Col2"), F.col("Col3")).alias("NewCol2")
)

result_df_struct = example_df.select(
    "Col1", F.struct(F.col("Col2"), F.col("Col3")).alias("NewCol2")
)
result_df_array.show()
result_df_struct.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+
|Col1|NewCol2|
+----+-------+
|  11|[a, 13]|
|  21|[b, 23]|
+----+-------+

+----+-------+
|Col1|NewCol2|
+----+-------+
|  11|{a, 13}|
|  21|{b, 23}|
+----+-------+
```

Note that the the `Col3` will be cast to a string when you put it in an array.

With the struct column you can access fields by name, and with the array column you can access items by index:

```
result_df_array.select(F.col("NewCol2").getItem(1)).show()
result_df_struct.select(F.col("NewCol2").getField("Col2")).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|NewCol2[1]|
+----------+
|        13|
|        23|
+----------+

+------------+
|NewCol2.Col2|
+------------+
|           a|
|           b|
+------------+
```

I don't think spark has an ordered collection datatype that can contain elements with mixed type.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot for the additional info on access and type limitation! Godspeed! :)